# translate mongo query to spring-data-mongo query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a query crafted with mongoPlayground [here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bo1yAPh0spf)

```
db.Workflow.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tasks"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "workflow": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      workflowTask: "$tasks",
      workflow: "$workflow"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "workflowTask.workflow": "$workflow"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "workflowTask.workflow.tasks",
      "workflow",
      "_id"
    ]
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [
        {
          $skip: 0
        },
        {
          $limit: 30
        },
        
      ],
      count: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      
    }
  }
])
```

I have a hard time converting this to spring-data-mongo Aggregation Objects!

To be more precise:

- match is fine
- unwind is fine
- project is fine

it seems the $$ROOT variable is not working in spring-data!
Also, $set and $unset seems unsupported?
And finally, for the facet, i can produce the data[] part, but unable to produce the count:{ total: xx}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Spring Data MongoDB are you using? With version 2.5.0, each operation works the following way.

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(new Criteria());
UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("tasks");
AddFieldsOperation addFieldsOperation = Aggregation.addFields().addField("workflow").withValue("$$ROOT").build();
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("_id").and("tasks").as("workflowTask").and("workflow").as("workflow");
SetOperation setOperation = SetOperation.builder().set("workflowTask.workflow").toValueOf("workflow");
UnsetOperation unsetOperation = UnsetOperation.unset("workflowTask.workflow.tasks", "workflow", "_id");
FacetOperation facetOperation = Aggregation.facet()
        .and(Aggregation.skip(0L), Aggregation.limit(30))
        .as("data")
        .and(Aggregation.group().count().as("total"))
        .as("count");
```

Set and Unset are not available in Aggregation class but they can be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed, Spring-Data does not allow defining all legitimate MongoDB queries. 
But, you can do a trick:

All Spring-Data `AggregationOperation` implementations (`MatchOperation`, `AggregationOperation`, ...) turns into `org.bson.Document`.
All you need to do is implement `AggregationOperation` with MongoDB JSON query:

- Calling builder: `new Document("$unwind", "$tasks")`
- From JSON: `Document.parse("{\"$unwind\": \"$tasks\"}")`

---

```
// Define aggregation pipelines
List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

//$addFields
pipeline.add(Aggregation.addFields().addFieldWithValue("workflow", "$$ROOT").build());

//$unset
pipeline.add(agg -> new Document("$unset", 
    Arrays.asList(
        "workflowTask.workflow.tasks",
        "workflow",
        "_id")));

//$facet
pipeline.add(agg -> new Document("$facet", ...))
```

[AggregationOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOperation.html)